# Optimize slow Wordpress Query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have one query that takes several seconds to execute. I'm using version 5.7.19.

```
SELECT 
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*, 
    SUM( IFNULL( pvc.count, 0 ) ) AS post_views 
FROM 
    wp_posts 
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
        ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
    LEFT JOIN wp_post_views pvc 
        ON pvc.id = wp_posts.ID 
           AND pvc.type = 0 
           AND STR_TO_DATE(pvc.period, '%Y%m%d') BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() 
WHERE 
    1=1 
    AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) ) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
    AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY 
    wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY 
    post_views DESC,  wp_posts.ID DESC 
LIMIT 
    0, 16 ;
```

The stripped down result:

```
+-------+------------+
| ID    | post_views |
+-------+------------+
| 25324 |       8037 |
| 30866 |       6442 |
| 27720 |       5974 |
| 30161 |       5354 |
| 31207 |       5028 |
| 11901 |       4851 |
| 30739 |       4271 |
|  3331 |       3723 |
|   436 |       3685 |
| 14980 |       3250 |
| 31297 |       3087 |
|  3745 |       3019 |
| 29858 |       2945 |
|  2503 |       2882 |
|   416 |       2880 |
| 23773 |       2577 |
+-------+------------+
```

Result of the `EXPLAIN` query

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                 | key                  | key_len | ref                                               | rows | filtered | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_term_relationships | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,term_taxonomy_id                                      | term_taxonomy_id     | 8       | const                                             | 2190 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_posts              | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,post_name,type_status_date,post_parent,post_author,ID | PRIMARY              | 8       | wpHdStreams.wp_term_relationships.object_id       |    1 |     7.80 | Using where                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pvc                   | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,id_type_period_count,type_period_count,id             | id_type_period_count | 9       | wpHdStreams.wp_term_relationships.object_id,const |   16 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I optimize the query? Currently it took at least 2.5 seconds to execute it.

EDIT:

Here are the three tables:
`wp_posts`

```
| wp_posts | CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
`ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
`post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
`post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
`post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
`comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
`ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
`post_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`to_ping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
`pinged` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
`post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
`post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
`post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
KEY `post_author` (`post_author`),
KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33551 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
```

`wp_term_relationships`

```
| wp_term_relationships | CREATE TABLE `wp_term_relationships` (
`object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`term_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`,`term_taxonomy_id`),
KEY `term_taxonomy_id` (`term_taxonomy_id`),
KEY `object_id` (`object_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
```

`wp_post_views`

```
| wp_post_views | CREATE TABLE `wp_post_views` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `period` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `count` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`type`,`period`,`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_type_period_count` (`id`,`type`,`period`,`count`) USING BTREE,
KEY `type_period_count` (`type`,`period`,`count`) USING BTREE,
KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
```

`type` indicates the type of the value:

1. 0 = Year with month and day (Ymd)
2. 1 = Year with (i think it was) week
3. 2 = Year with month (Ym)
4. 3 = Year (Y)
5. 4 = total

It's this plugin [post views counter](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/)

Answer (score 2):

Without `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, I can only guess...

If `wp_term_relationships` is a many:many mapping table, then follow the schema tips seen in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

If any of those tables is a variant of `wp_postmeta`, then see the tips in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Also,... Check the math.  Often, this pattern comes up with inflated aggregates:

```
SELECT SUM(...)
    FROM x JOIN y ...
    GROUP BY ...
```

I call it the "inflate-deflate syndrome.  After seeing the schema, I may have more comments.  If we can get rid of it then we can get rid of the `GROUP BY`, which is currently preventing any optimization of the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT`.

The gist of the 'fix' will be to turn `post_views` into a subquery that has all the `JOINing` in it.  That gets rid of the regular `JOIN` and the `GROUP BY`.  Once you have done all that, do the `IFNULL` outside the `SUM`.

`STR_TO_DATE(pvc.period, '%Y%m%d')` is hiding a potentially indexable column inside a function.  If `period` is a `DATE` datatype, then that is identical `pvc.period`.  Even if it is a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, it should be fine in this context.  If it `VARCHAR`, then shame on you (or on WP?).

**More** (based on schema)

For pvc, this will cut out the redundant indexes:  Replace the 4 you have with these 2.  (It will not inpact the current query.)

```
PRIMARY KEY(id, type, period),
INDEX(type, period, count, id)
```

See my link for avoiding the `191`.  (Again, won't impact the current query, but might greatly help others.)

If you can't change `period` to a `DATE` (and it looks like you cannot), then the goal is to keep it as a string and aim for

```
pvc.period BETWEEN CONCAT('', (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY))
               AND CONCAT('',  NOW())
```

(I don't know if the bogus `CONCATs` are necessary to change those dates into strings.)  Notice how the indexed `period` is standing alone, not hidden inside a function call.

Be sure to do likewise for the other "types".

Keep in mind that WP and all its plugins seem to be designed for "small" databases.  You have come to me to figure out how to use MySQL to improve performance and scalability, that they have yet to consider.

I think that `LEFT JOIN` should be changed to simply `JOIN`.  After all, if the 'right' table is missing, you want `0` in the `SUM`, so why bother creating `NULLs` to have to turn into `0`.

Don't use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` unless it is important.  It involves doing virtually all of the query as if the `LIMIT` were absent.  (And, again, the return value may be inflated.)

This might come closer:

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.*,
        IFNULL( (
                SELECT  SUM(pvc.count)
                    FROM  wp_post_views AS pvc  ON pvc.id = p.ID
                    WHERE  pvc.type = 0
                      AND  pvc.period BETWEEN ... AND ... ),
         0 ) AS post_views
    WHERE  p.post_type = 'post'
      AND  p.post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY  post_views DESC, p.ID DESC
    LIMIT  0, 16
```

I got rid of `wp_term_relationships` since it is unused.  Note: the `LEFT` says that it does not matter whether there is a matching row or not.

Comment: I added the schema for the particitpating tables.

Comment: I edited the post and added the schema for the particitpating tables.
Seems like it's a `VARCHAR`. I found the plugin and it made what I need. Didn't know that `VARCHAR` has such an impact. Is there even a way to save different `type`s as the author did in a single column with a `DATE` or even a `TIMESAMP`? But maybe you can achieve the same functionality with the `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions of mysql?

How can you achieve a sort by `post_views` with a subquery?

Comment: It depends.  What are some sample values of that `VARCHAR`?  It may be practical to compare it as a string instead of a `DATE`.

Comment: See my link for how to get rid of `191`, it is probably hurting you in _other_ queries.

Comment: I will take care of the `191`. thanks for this hint.
According to your answer, I came up with following query: (See bext comment). But I receive always 0 views on every post. What mistake did I make? The `term_relationship` is used, but doesn't matter atm. I use a nginx cache to cache all posts. This reduces a lot of queries and php execution because it only serves html files.

Comment: `SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.*,
  IFNULL( (
                SELECT  SUM(pvc.count)
                    FROM  wp_post_views AS pvc JOIN wp_posts ON pvc.id = wp_posts.ID
                    WHERE  pvc.type = 0
                        AND  pvc.period BETWEEN CONCAT('', ((NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY))
                           AND CONCAT('',  (NOW()))
                    ) ,
         0 ) AS post_views
       FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
      AND  wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY  post_views DESC, wp_posts.ID DESC
    LIMIT  0, 16`

Comment: It seems that the problem is in the between clause. For testing I tried the original with `STR_TO_DATE` and it shows me a view value. But as a result I receive the same number of views for each post and the number of post_views seems to be the overall views from all posts summed up.

Comment: Did you change `period` to be `DATE` or `DATETIME`?